# Radio Button Change Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having 2 Radio Buttons.(For Ex : ID and Name)..

```
  <%=Html.RadioButton("Emp","1")%>
  <label>ID</label>
  <%=Html.RadioButton("Emp","2")%>
  <label>Name</label>
```

If i click the Name,

```
<p>
   <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyDate)%>:&nbsp;
   <%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDate) %>
</p>
```

the above control should be visibled false..How to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$(':radio[value=2]').click(function() {
    // Might need to adjust the selector here based 
    // on the field you would like to hide
    $('#MyDate').hide();
});
```

or if you want to use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```
$(':radio[name=Emp]').change(function() {
    // read the value of the selected radio
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == '2') {
        $('#MyDate').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to hide this fully...what to do.... <p>
      <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyNameNM)%>:&nbsp;
      <%= Html.DropDownList("lstProducts", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Emps"], "Id", "Name"), new { onChange = "onSelectedIndexChanged(this)" })%> 
      <%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyNameNM)%> --> &nbsp;<%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.NormalMethod)%>
   </p>

Comment: Wrap it in a div with a given id and use this id to hide : `$('#mydivid').hide();`

Comment: i had given like this...
       $(':radio[value=1]').click(function () {
           $('#Normal').show();
           $('#JQuery').hide();
       });

       $(':radio[value=2]').click(function () {
           $('#JQuery').show();
           $('#Normal').hide();

       });      .......... Whenever i click the First radio button,second div visible false is working. But, when i click the second radio button nothing happens...

Comment: and also i want the div to be visible false initially. so i had given like this...<div id="Normal" visible="false"> ...this also not working

Comment: Your second method taken me to the right path...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use other approach...

```
<form method="post" id="ChangeEvent">
      <%: Html.RadioButton("A1", "1", ViewData["IsSelected"] == "1", new { onclick = "document.getElementById('ChangeEvent').submit();" })%> Active
        <%: Html.RadioButton("A1", "2", ViewData["IsSelected"] == "2", new { onclick = "document.getElementById('ChangeEvent').submit();" })%> Not Active
        <%: Html.RadioButton("A1", "3", ViewData["IsSelected"] == "3", new { onclick = "document.getElementById('ChangeEvent').submit();" })%> All
</form>
```

Under code behind use **Request.Form["A1"]** to get selected value...

Enjoy! :)