# Radio Button Selection Change Event Doesn't fire in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show hide images based on selection of radio button.  But it seems the jQuery script never fires up on selection change.  My code looks like below

```
    @Html.Label("Select Chart Type")
            @Html.RadioButton("rbChartType", "1", isChecked: true) @Html.Label("Chart1")
            @Html.RadioButton("rbChartType", "2", isChecked: false) @Html.Label("Chart2")
 <img src="@Url.Action("GetChart1")" alt="Billing Graph" class="img-responsive" id="imgChart1" />
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetChart2")" alt="Usage Graph" class="img-responsive" id="imgChart2" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='rbChartType']").change(function () {
        alert('hi');
        var selectedRadio = $("input[name='rbChartType']:checked").val();
        if (selectedRadio == 1) {
            $('#imgChart1').show();
            $('#imgChart2').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#imgChart1').hide();
            $('#imgChart2').show();
        }
    });
});
```

I could not see my alert firing up!!

Comment: any errors in debugger console?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202799/radio-button-change-event

Comment: @devlin, that was the example I tried already; I'm not sure what the mistake i'm doing but that one also didn't work!! Do I need to have a form around radio buttons? I hv tried that too but it didn't work

Comment: @Dandy, yes, I do get an error in debugger - "Empty string passed to getElementById()" but this is coming from jquery. I guess there is something wrong in my html or script which I could not figure it out

Comment: it can't find the input.  the example I linked above shows you how to target the radio input.  $(':radio[name=rbChartType]')

Comment: your javascript code is fine, something wrong with your html markup. https://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/bpbgg8y8/ . Share you view-source html markup.

Comment: Add the HTML that is generated by the HTML helpers to this question. And since you are inside the change event, you can get to the selected element by simply saying: var selectedRadio = $(this).val();

Comment: Are you using any third party validation libraries? Does typing $("input[name='rbChartType']").length into your console display a number other than zero? Also, you can further simplify your code using jQuery's toggle() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to select the radio button by name ( atleast not in the event handler) you could do it with a classname if you had many radiobuttons.

Second, if you set your elements to `visibility:hidden` you can show it again using `$("imgChart2").css('visibility', 'visible');`. Or alternatively set it to `display:none` and stick with `show()` to show it.

Try this:

```
@Html.Label("Select Chart Type")
@Html.RadioButton("rbChartType", "1", isChecked: true) @Html.Label("Chart1")
@Html.RadioButton("rbChartType", "2", isChecked: false) @Html.Label("Chart2")

<img src="@Url.Action("GetChart1")" alt="Billing Graph" class="img-responsive" id="imgChart1" />
<img src="@Url.Action("GetChart2")" alt="Usage Graph" class="img-responsive" id="imgChart2" style="display:none" />

@section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("input:radio").on("change", function () {

            if ($(this).val() == "1") {
                $('#imgChart1').show();
                $('#imgChart2').hide();
            } else {
                $('#imgChart1').hide();
                $('#imgChart2').show();
            }
        });

    });

</script>


}
```

Comment: I figured the issue... I have not added @section scripts{ } around my javascript in mvc.  I understand the issue with "visibility".  Thanks for your snippet.  It has the clue to solve my problem!!

Comment: @user2169261 no problems!